# getting error in animation at R.anim.down_from_top : R.anim.up_from_bottom);

Tags: android

```html
package com.example.yourapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  
 private List<Food> listFood = null;
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 Context context;
 private int lastPosition = -1;
 
 // constructeur
 public FoodListAdapter(Context context, List<Food> listFood) {
  this.listFood = listFood;
  layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.listFood = listFood;
  this.context = context;
 
 }
 
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return listFood.size();
 }
 
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return listFood.get(position);
 }
 
 @Override
 public long getItemId(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return arg0;
 }
 
 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView nomView;
  TextView priceView;
  ImageView pictureView;
 
 }
 
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
 
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   // initialisation des vues
   holder.nomView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
   holder.priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
   holder.pictureView = (ImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.picture);
 
   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  // affchier les données convenablement dans leurs positions
  holder.nomView.setText(listFood.get(position).getName());
  holder.priceView.setText(String.valueOf(listFood.get(position)
    .getPrice()) + " $");
  holder.pictureView.setBackgroundDrawable(listFood.get(position)
    .getPicture());
  
  // changer R.anim.ton_effet
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
    (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.down_from_top
      : R.anim.up_from_bottom);
  
  convertView.startAnimation(animation);
  lastPosition = position;
  return convertView;
 
 }
}
```

error is down_from_top cannot be resolved or is not a field
iam just created a grid view in this example
is it error in xml or java file...help me pls thanks in advance...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Do you have a _down_from_top.xml_ and a _up_from_bottom.xml_ file in your _res/anim_ directory?

Comment: no        what u mean by down from top and up xml is it use for animation i dont hav that file

Comment: When you say `R.anim.down_from_top` in your Java code, you are eventually referencing a _down_from_top.xml_ file in your _res/anim_ directory (through the `R` class). If you are following some tutorial, make sure you don't skip any steps.

Comment: To follow up on what @Voicu said, you need to have the `R.anim.down_from_top` file as it will have the animation defined. It is not a default animation for Android. It is your custom defined animation and you must define it.

Comment: thanku sir...but i dont hav anim xml file..from where i get xml for those two?